# how can i change the state of parent component through the context?

Tags: reactjs, search

I want to implement the search component, i get the search content through the search component and use this content in parent component, i have used Context to use some methods in another children and also in search which is a child. now how can i change the state in Home through the search.

my search component is :

```
    import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
    import PhoneBookContext from "../Context/PhoneBookContext";

    function Search() {
    const phoneBookContext = useContext(PhoneBookContext);
    function handleSearchVal(e) {
    var searchValue = e.target.value;
    phoneBookContext.searchVal = searchValue;
    }
    return (
    <>
      <ButtonToolbar
        className="justify-content-between"
        aria-label="Toolbar with Button groups"
      >
        <InputGroup>
          <InputGroup.Text id="btnGroupAddon2">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="16"
              height="16"
              fill="currentColor"
              className="bi bi-search"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              onClick={phoneBookContext.handleSearchClick}
            >
              <path d="">
            </svg>
          </InputGroup.Text>
          <Form.Control
            type="search"
            placeholder="search"
            aria-label="Input group example"
            aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon2"
            onChange={(e) => handleSearchVal(e)}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default Search;

my Home component

     import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
     import Search from "./Search";

     //Import Context
     import PhoneBookContext from "../Context/PhoneBookContext";

     function Home() {
     var contactList;
     let filterBySearch;

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data")) && Data) {
    const mergeArrayOfObjects = (original, newdata, selector = "key") => {
      newdata.forEach((dat) => {
        const foundIndex = original.findIndex(
          (ori) => ori[selector] == dat[selector]
        );
        if (foundIndex >= 0) {
          console.log("something wrong");
        } else original.push(dat);
      });
      return original;
    };
    contactList = mergeArrayOfObjects(
      Data,
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data")),
      "name"
    );
  } else if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data"))) {
    contactList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Data"));
  } else {
    contactList = Data;
  }

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(contactList);
  const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState("");

  function HandleSearchClick() {
    setSearchVal(searchVal);
    if (searchVal === "") {
      setContacts(contactList);
      document.location.reload(true);
      return;
    }
    filterBySearch = contactList.filter((Item) => {
      console.log(searchVal);
      if (Item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) {
        return Item;
      }
    });
    setContacts(filterBySearch);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <PhoneBookContext.Provider
        value={{
          contactList: contactList,
          contacts: contacts,
          handleSearchClick: HandleSearchClick,
          searchVal: SearchVal,
        }}
      >
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div className="title">
            <Title />
          </div>
          <div className="search">
            <Search />
          </div>
        </div>
        <ToolBar />
        <PaginatedItems itemsPerPage={10} />
      </PhoneBookContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: i want to change this state setSearchVal(with content which i receive in search component)